# BaseColumns does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm porting an Android Studio project to Visual Studio / Xamarin.
I have this Java code:

```
public class EmployeeDataContract {
    public EmployeeDataContract() { }

    public static abstract class EmployeeDataEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tblEmployeeData"; // Local SQLLite table
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LOCAL_ID = "_id";
```

translated to C#:

```
public class EmployeeDataContract {
    public EmployeeDataContract() {}

    public abstract class EmployeeDataEntry : BaseColumns  { // had to remove "static"
        public const string TABLE_NAME = "tblEmployeeData"; // Local SQLLite table
        public const string COLUMN_NAME_LOG_ID = "_id";
```

Visual Studio gives the compile error:
*BaseColumns does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*

So then I go look at the `BaseColumns` and it doesn't contain a constructor, nor does it inherit a class (that might have a constructor), therefore it inherits from `Object`, which should have a constructor with 0 arguments.

What is the problem?

Comment: Looking at the Java code, it seems `BaseColumns` is an interface.

Comment: Yes, it is. However, `BaseColumns` in the C# wrapper is a class, so that's what I have to work with.

Comment: I can guess there is no public/protected contructor of `BaseColumns` is available. To use SQLite in Xamrian.Android might this help https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/data/sqlite/create_a_database_with_sqlitenet/

Comment: Exactly, no constructor is available in `BaseColumns`, as if it were not intended to be subclassed, yet it is not declared `sealed` and it does by default inherit from `Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug report about this behavior here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=36791

Basically in Java this interface contains just two constants, defining names of id and count columns. In C# interfaces cannot contain constants, so such constants are moved to an abstract class like you see. It cannot be inherited (in other assemblies), because it's only constructor is internal, and child class should call parent's constructor. Because this interface contains *only* constants, xamarin does not generate (empty) interface for it.

If you are porting code manually (not binding to a Java library) - *maybe* you can ignore inheriting from this class, since it does not provide anything useful anyway. Of course some another code might only accept instances of this class, but that is unlikely.

Comment: In retrospect, the only reason I would want to use the inherited interface/class is for the definition of `count`. Looking at my Java code, I see that I don't use it. I created my own definition for `id`  for aesthetics, i.e. so it would match my other column names, so no, I don't need the class.

Comment: You can as well use BaseColumns.Count in the same way, without inheritance (it's static member of that abstract BaseColumns class).